# Trying to validate c# program for alphabet. It pops up various errors. I am unable to find where I am wrong

Tags: c#

> Error: "Too many characters  in character literal."

If we replace XL with X,it pops up a error saying

> "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and
>   'bool'"

Any suggestions to make it work? I appreciate your valuable time.

```
Console.WriteLine("plan: ");

string plan = Console.ReadLine();

if (plan.Length = 0 || plan.ToUpper()[0] == 'S' || 
    plan.ToUpper()[0] == 'M' || plan.ToUpper()[0] == 'L' || 
    plan.ToUpper()[0] == 'XL')
{
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: `XL` can't be a character. It can be a string. Also `plan.Length = 0` should be `plan.Length == 0`.

Comment: you are trying to assign a value to `plan.Length`  change `plan.Length = 0`

Comment: `plan.Length = 0` should be: `plan.Length == 0`.

Comment: by `plan.ToUpper()[0] == 'XL'` do you want to check that if string starts with `XL` ? then write `plan.ToUpper().StartsWith("XL");` instead

Answer (score 0):

'XL' is not one character.
Maybe you need compare strings:

```
Console.WriteLine("plan: ");

string plan = Console.ReadLine();

if (plan.Length == 0 || plan.ToUpper() == "S" || 
    plan.ToUpper() == "M" || plan.ToUpper() == "L" || 
    plan.ToUpper() == "XL")
{
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: the equality operator is wrong too. `plan.Length = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The result of `plan.Length = 0` is int. For comparison you should use `==`.

Single quote is for single chars. For strings use double quotes:

```
Console.WriteLine("plan: ");

string plan = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();

if (plan.Length == 0 ||
    plan == "S" ||
    plan == "M" ||
    plan == "L" ||
    plan == "XL")
{
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```